# mac laptop late 2008

Tags: macbook-pro

ubuntu 18.04 will not recover from laptop lid closed and reopened. Must switch laptop off and back on. Works fine if the lid is left open. It will go dark and recover to the password screen.

Comment: Please read [ask], then [edit] to clarify: What is your question? What research have you done, and what have you tried? Also use a descriptive title.

Answer (score 0):

There is usually a "wake up" key on the keyboard ('`Fn` key or else). Does it work after you open the lid?

In some cases iti s just the display driver that does not light up the screen. Again, using the keyboard keys that change screen luminosity could light up the screen.